# fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None When using Swift with Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've followed this connect your swift application to Parse.com tutorial: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/connect-your-swift-application-to-parse-com/ and it worked great. This tutorial only shows you how to place data on the Parse.com service. So I did some research into how to retrieve data.

In the First tutorial it says to add data to Parse like so:

```
    Parse.setApplicationId("your_application_key", clientKey: "your_client_key")

    var object = PFObject(className: "testDataClass")
    object.addObject("iOSBlog", forKey: "websiteUrl")
    object.addObject("Five", forKey: "websiteRating")
    object.save()
```

In the second tutorial, wrote by the Parse team (http://blog.parse.com/2014/06/06/building-apps-with-parse-and-swift/) It says to write it like this:

```
var gameScore = PFObject(className: "GameScore")
gameScore.setObject(1337, forKey: "score")
gameScore.setObject("Sean Plott", forKey: "playerName")
gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { 
    (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if success {
        NSLog("Object created with id: \(gameScore.objectId)")
    } else {
        NSLog("%@", error)
    }
}
```

and then to retrieve it, use this code:

```
 var query = PFQuery(className: "GameScore")
 query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(gameScore.objectId) {
 (scoreAgain: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
     if !error {
        NSLog("%@", scoreAgain.objectForKey("playerName") as NSString)
     } else {
        NSLog("%@", error)
    }
}
```

However, When I use the Official Parse code I get the following error:

```
fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
(lldb)
```

and All these things happen in almost every pane of Xcode:

[image: xcodeDebug]

Can someone tell me what is wrong and how to fix it? I am relatively new to Xcode and Swift so I would really appreciate a layman terms answer.

**EDIT** Here is the appDelegate.swift function

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    // Connect to Parse using the keys provided

    Parse.setApplicationId("xxx", clientKey: "xxx")

    // Store Data to Parse

    var gameScore = PFObject(className: "GameScore")
    gameScore.setObject(1337, forKey: "score")
    gameScore.setObject("Sean Plott", forKey: "playerName")
    gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if success {
            NSLog("Object created with id: \(gameScore.objectId)")
        } else {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        }
    }

    var query = PFQuery(className: "GameScore")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(gameScore.objectId) {
        (scoreAgain: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if !error {
            NSLog("%@", scoreAgain.objectForKey("playerName") as NSString)
        } else {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        }
    }



    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Much appreciated.

Added new code for user to see:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    // Connect to Parse using the keys provided

    Parse.setApplicationId("xxxx", clientKey: "xxxx")

    // Store Data to Parse

    var gameScore = PFObject(className: "GameScore")
    gameScore.setObject(1337, forKey: "score")
    gameScore.setObject("Sean Plott", forKey: "playerName")
    gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (success ?? false) {
            NSLog("Object created with id: \(gameScore.objectId)")
        } else {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        }
    }

    var query = PFQuery(className: "GameScore")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(gameScore.objectId) {
        (scoreAgain: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            NSLog("%@", scoreAgain.objectForKey("playerName") as NSString)
        } else {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        }
    }



    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Comment: What is your `NSLog` output? Is your object created with an ID, or is an error printed? In any case, this sounds like it might be a Parse bug. If it can't find the object, I would assume it to execute the callback with an `NSError` instance provided.

Comment: I'm surprised this compiles.  Try replacing `if !error` with `if error != nil`.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed your stack trace actually does call the callback. Does `scoreAgain` actually have a value? Can you try comparing it to `nil` before using it? If not, I would suggest you change the method signature for the callback to: `(scoreAgain: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void`, to force your code to check for a value.

Comment: Sorry, try replacing `if !error` with `if error == nil`.

Comment: @CraigOtis  changed the line to match this: (scoreAgain: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void and then I get this error: PFObject does not have a number named 'objectForKey' - Really sorry as I said i'm a little bit of a noob and I have no idea how to fix this. :(

Comment: @vacawama hey, Just tried the changing of !error to error == nil but still the same problem of: fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
(lldb)

Comment: @vacawama That still doesn't work.

Comment: In addition to that, change `if success` to `if (success ?? false)`.

Comment: @vacawama In addition? I have already changed the success once. Am I not seeing the second instance or do you mean change the one that is there already? I tried that with if (success ?? false) { and got this error Expected ',' separator

Comment: I realized the previous change to `success` wouldn't work.  Make sure you have spaces on both sides of `??` in `if (success ?? false)`

Comment: @vacawama Ive added the code to the original at the bottom - is this correct? im still getting the build failed error: Expected ',' separator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65424/discussion-between-vacawama-and-danniecoderboi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Parse example was written in June when Swift was in Beta.  Swift has continued to evolve, so some of the things they are doing are no longer legal in Swift.

Firstly, you can no longer check if an optional variable `error` is `nil` with `if !error`.  Instead you must explicitly check against `nil` like this: `if error == nil`.

Secondly, `success` is declared as an implicitly unwrapped optional.  It is no longer valid to check if it is `true` with `if success`.  You could do `if success == true` but this will crash if `success` is `nil`.  Instead, you could do `if (success ?? false)`.  This uses the *nil coalescing operator* to safely unwrap the optional `Bool` if it has a value or it uses `false` if the `Bool` is `nil`. Either way, the `if` will only succeed if the `Bool` is `true`.

Comment: Note that comparing an `Optional<T>` to a `T`, as in `if success == true`, is actually a safe operation. When you define `==` on a type, Swift automatically wires up the comparison cases where one or the other or both `T`s are `nil`.

Comment: @rikkigibson, if  `success` is declared as `Bool!` and it is `nil`, it will crash to do `if success == nil` with `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I just verified that in a Playground.  If `success` is `Bool?`, then you can do `if success == nil` and it won't crash.

Comment: Good to know. Call it reason number 543 to not use implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Comment: Yeah, they are dangerous.  They are good for properties that you know will be set before they are used (like how iOS uses them for IBOutlets).

Comment: @rikkigibson.  I misspoke.  I meant to say, if success is declared as `Bool!` and it is `nil`, it will crash to do `if success == true` with `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I just verified that in a Playground. If success is `Bool?`, then you can do `if success == true` and it won't crash.  You can do `if success == nil` for both `success` declared as `Bool!` and `Bool?`.